# React Native margin acts inside of object, not outside

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

Go to https://snack.expo.io/HJV601djf and open `login_screen/components/Form.js`. As you can see, the `textInput` has the style

```
  textInput: {
    flex:1,
    height: 50,
    marginBottom: 20
  }
```

You can see that the user icons are not aligned with the text input. If I take `marginBottom` out, everything goes ok, but with `marginBottom: 20` the icons get dealigned. I can probably fix that by making the text input get aligned vertically too, but I'll not know the cause of the problem.

How can `marginBottom` affect the insides of `UserInput` if it's supposed to add space only on the outside?

Printscreen if you don't want to wait to load the app:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because , in your `UserInput.js`, you are trying to **merge the styles for the `textInput`** while the `Image / Icon` styles are remaining the same, *therefore it is misaligned*.

The optimum way to solve this would be to add a `textInputContainer` style to the component and set the margin to it as

**TextInput.js**

```
<View style={mergeObjects(this.props.containerStyle ? StyleSheet.flatten(this.props.containerStyle) : {}, StyleSheet.flatten(styles.inputWrapper))}>
```

**Form.js**

```
<UserInput
          containerStyle={styles.textInputContainer}
          style={styles.textInput}
          source={{uri:'http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/user-icon-74490.png'}}
          placeholder="e-mail"
          autoCapitalize={'none'}
          returnKeyType={'done'}
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
```

and the **styles**

```
textInputContainer : {
        marginBottom: 20
  },
```

Here's the [**snack**](https://snack.expo.io/BJxxk-OoM) for the same